# Open Image In Canva Editor

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want to open a Image in [Canva](https://www.canva.com/) Using JavaScript

```html
<img src="myImage.png">
<button id="imgBtn">Open In Canva</button>
```

```js
function openInCanva() {
  // this is where i want a way to open my image in Canva
}
var button = document.getElementById("imgBtn");
button.addEventListener("click", openInCanva)
```

I have this simple image, and a button i want is when i click on the button my Image gets opened in Canva Editor

Comment: You mean somehow send that image to the canva website's editor?

Comment: you may have to contact **Canva** customer support to get API guide, due to the editor service is not free, you may have to create one account and get auth token before post your image to its editor through the APIs.

Comment: @ChrisG Yes that's what i want